# Swift XCode Pulling data from a website using a task, but I am unable to get the data then into my other functions to display it with TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, task

So, I am using a task to pull data from a website. The data is successfully pulled and stored in the variable: var firstTeam as shown below (in viewDidLoad)

```
    // Pull data from Website
        var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.clemsontigers.com/SportSelect.dbml?SPSID=657771&SPID=103701")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){(data, response, error) in

        let content = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        var contentArray = content!.componentsSeparatedByString("<td class=\"opponent\">")

        var stopArray = contentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</td>")

        firstTeam = stopArray[0] as! String

        println(firstTeam)


            }
        task.resume()
```

However, now I would like to use the firstTeam string to populate my TableView. However, I get an error if I use firstTeam in my function (after didReceiveMemoryWarning):

```
    //ALL OF THE STUFF TO ADD DATA TO THE TABLE

func setUpSchedule() {

    var schedule1 = ScheduleRow(team: "Opponent", date: "Date", score: "Score")

    var schedule2 = ScheduleRow(team: "Team1", date: "Date1", score: "Score1")
    .....
```

so, how do I make a string variable that I can put data into with my task, but then use in another function to fill my custom TableView?

I would greatly appreciate any and all help!

Comment: You can correct indenting in Xcode by selecting the lines and control-i –  zaph 13 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, all I had to do was use a global variable and declare it outside of the class. So if you have a similar problem, just declare your variable outside of the class.

Comment: Global variables are not the way to go.